# How to display a binary search tree using CSS, HTML and a bit of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, binary-search-tree

I want to "paint" the tree on screen using CSS and HTML and not represent it in any way or data structure ...

Comment: http://keithcarpenter.blogspot.com/2013/01/binary-search-trees-using-javascript.html
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/09/computer-science-in-javascript-binary-search-tree-part-1/
http://blog.yojimbocorp.com/2012/08/21/introduction-to-data-structures-and-algorithms-in-javascript-binary-search-tree/
https://gist.github.com/trevmex/821973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **very simple** way of creating a tree-like structure with HTML and CSS is nesting `<div>`s
Each `div` represents a node, and can have multiple nodes inside:

```
<div> //root
    <div> //child 1
        <div> //child 1.1
            <div></div> //child 1.1.1
            <div></div> //child 1.1.2
            <div></div> //child 1.1.3
        </div>
        <div></div> //child 1.2
    </div>
    <div></div> //child 2
</div>
```

Then you can add a `margin-top` to all divs, so that they appear under its parent div.

A JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VxRmc/

I've added percentage widths to each div. You can calculate widths if you know how many childs a node has. Or you can use fixed widths...

Yeah, it's not a beautiful tree, but it can't be simpler.

Answer (score 30):

Unlimited binary and unilevel tree with CSS:

```css
.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li div:hover,
.tree li div:hover+ul li div {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

.tree li div:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li div:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li div:hover+ul::before,
.tree li div:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div><input type="checkbox"> Main <br/> <button> Test Btn </button></div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div><input type="checkbox"> Sub-1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div><input type="checkbox"> Sub-2</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div><input type="checkbox"> Sub-2-1</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div><input type="checkbox"> Sub-2-2</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also available on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Limitlessisa/5Lhb0ron/)

Comment: This is a really nice snippet. Ty

Comment: Amazing pure CSS solution!