# How to represent a binary tree using HTML (TOP to BOTTOM)?

Tags: html, css

I want to design binary tree for my MLM website. I attach one image how I want the tree.

**Binary Tree:**
[image]

Comment: Where is your tried code?

Comment: i want idea for write code.

Comment: See the Link [See the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000341/how-to-display-a-binary-search-tree-using-css-html-and-a-bit-of-javascript) Thanks

Comment: You can Refer this link: [See the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000341/how-to-display-a-binary-search-tree-using-css-html-and-a-bit-of-javascript) thnaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many jquery plugins to design Tree structure, for example try this one.http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Create-An-Editable-Organization-Chart-with-jQuery-orgChart-Plugin.html