# How to display an mlm binary genealogy in php?

Tags: php, html, css, binary-tree

Hi and good day to you guys, I'm trying to create an mlm binary genealogy in php for my project, I'm stuck at creating/displaying the genealogy tree. I've search everywhere and got this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000341/how-to-display-a-binary-search-tree-using-css-html-and-a-bit-of-javascript) the second answer by Limitless isa this is her [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Limitlessisa/5Lhb0ron/). I'v tried to implement it using my function and so far I'm getting nowhere.

Attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEGN0.png) is my database for accounts, and this is my code

```
    <div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div><input type="checkbox">181210-1-105547-1<br/> <button> Test Btn </button></div>
      <ul>

<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $name = 'mlm';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';

    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' .$host .';dbname=' .$name;
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
    );
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

    function displayChildren($parent) {
        global $conn;

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE sponsorUpline = ?');
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $parent);
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            echo '<li></div><input type="checkbox">' .$row->serialNumber .'</div></li>';
            displayChildren($row->serialNumber);
        }
  }

    displayChildren('181210-1-105547-1');

?>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If anyone could help me with this and explain to me why it's not working would be wonderful.